# Must we close weakly to apply the spectral theorem?

Tags: c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, oa.operator-algebras

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable complex Hilbert space. All C*-subalgebras of $B(H)$ are assumed to be non-degenerate.

The spectral projections of a self-adjoint element $T$ of $B(H)$ lie in the weakly closed algebra generated by $T$.  In the early 1970s Pedersen [proved](http://blms.oxfordjournals.org/cgi/reprint/4/2/171) that if a C*-subalgebra $A$ of $B(H)$ contains all of the spectral projections of each of its self-adjoint elements, then $A$ is weakly closed.<sup>1</sup>  In his words, this "characterizes von Neumann algebras (on separable Hilbert spaces) as the only C*-algebras in which the spectral theorem can be used in its full force."<sup>2</sup>

On the other hand, suppose we start with an arbitrary C*-subalgebra $A$ of $B(H)$.  Must we go all the way to the weak closure to use the spectral theorem for self-adjoint elements of $A$?  If not, does iterating the process of taking the smallest C*-algebra in which we can apply the spectral theorem lead to the weak closure in a finite number of steps?  Pedersen asked this question over 30 years ago as a way to end a chapter on concrete C*-algebras,<sup>3</sup> and I don't know if it has been answered.  If the answer isn't known, I'd accept an answer giving a more recent reference that discusses this.  For the precise question, I'll just quote Pedersen:

> For any C*-subalgebra $A$ of $B(H)$ define $a(A)$ as the smallest C*-subalgebra of $B(H)$ containing all spectral projections of each self-adjoint element in $A$.  It is easy to verify that $A\subset a(A)\subset A''$.  If $H$ is separable is then $A''=a(A)$?  This failing, is $A''=a(a...a(A)...)$ (finitely many steps)?  Note that by 2.8.8 a transfinite (but countable) application of the operation $a$ will produce $A''$.

<sup>1</sup> G. Pedersen, [*C`*`-algebras and their automorphism groups*](http://outofprintmath.blogspot.com/2008/12/164-c-algebras-and-their-automorphism.html), Corollary 2.8.8, p. 38.

<sup>2</sup> Ibid., p. 39.

<sup>3</sup> Ibid.

Comment: What is the reasoning in "Note that by 2.8.8 a transfinite (but countable) application of the operation a will produce $A''$." ? I see that $\omega_1$ applications of the operation $a$ produce $A''$ and also that each element of $A''$ appears at the $\alpha$-th application for some $\alpha < \omega_1$; but why is $a^{\alpha}(A)=A''$ for some $\alpha < \omega_1$?

A related question: Is there some $\alpha < \omega_1$ which works for all $A \subset B(H)$?

Comment: Andreas: That is a good question, and I do not know the answer.  Perhaps I should have mentioned in the first place that I did not understand that line.  I included it as part of the quote for completeness, because I hoped it would add better context.  But in any case, I'm glad it inspired your question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/41597/transfinite-induction-a-theorem-of-pedersen-and-chains-of-subalgebras-of-bh